# Serializing objects with many-to-many relationships with Spring MVC, Jackson, and Hibernate

Tags: json, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

I am having a difficult time figuring out how to properly define and annotate the models in my web application so that they can be effectively used in both a web interface and REST web service.  Here is a simplified version of the relationship that is giving me trouble:

**Post model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POST")
public class Post implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "POST_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy-GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer postId;

    @Column(name = "POST_BODY")
    private String postBody;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @JoinTable(name = "POST_TAGS", 
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="POST_ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="TAG_ID")})
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<Tag>();

    //Getters and setters...
}
```

**Tag model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TAG")
public class Tag implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TAG_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy-GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer tagId;

    @Column(name = "TAG_NAME")
    private String tagName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="tags")
    private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<Post>();

    //Getters and setters...
}
```

I have one web service controller method for fetching all of the posts and one method for fetching all of the tags.  Each method should ideally return the list of the target class plus referenced classes.  For example:

```
[{
    postId: 1,
    postBody: "Hello world!",
    tags: [{
        tagId: 1,
        tagName: "hello"
    },{
        tagId: 2,
        tagName: "message"
    }]
}, { 
    postId: 2,
    ....
}]
```

But What I wind up seeing is an infinite recursion, as the returned tags for each post retrieve their associated post, which retrieve their associated tags, etc to infinity.  I have tried using `@JsonIgnore` on the getter methods of my classes, but then I am no longer getting the referenced objects.  I have tried using `@JsonIdentityInfo` to add IDs to my objects, but then I still get recursion, but only to the point where all references between the retrieved objects is exhausted.  I can't seem to find any documentation explaining how to handle situations like these, which seems like a common one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson's annotations for this (`@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`).

Check http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences

Or you can write your own serializer and keep track of what you've serialized already, which was what I ended up doing when I had to use Gson instead of Jackson.

Comment: How would `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` work for this example, though?  Both `Post` and `Tag` can be parent or children, depending on the context.

Comment: Well I guess I missed that part of the question. You can still create your own serializer for those objects, and then keep track of what you've serialized already.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote detailed usage of jackson hibernate module (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate)
Sorry for my bad english.

As described below at OP post - if we use default jackson + jackson-databind modules - we had some troubles with many-to-many serialization. It's an "infinite cycle" if we don't use @JsonIgnore + @JsonIdentityInfo annotations. And it is "ID as result" if we use both of them.

Best way to solve troubles - use module.
1. Add maven dep

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Create and use custom ObjectMapper

**HibernateAwareObjectMapper.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate4.Hibernate4Module;

public class HibernateAwareObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public HibernateAwareObjectMapper() {
        registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());
    }
}
```

3. Use this mapper in spring XML config

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="path.HibernateAwareObjectMapper"/>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

4. Add annotations to entities field.

Post entity don't need annotation.

Tag entity add @JsonIgnore annotation for fix "infinity loop" error.

Also we can change EAGER to LAZY fetchtype. And rule fetching by ObjectMapper config FORCE_LAZY_LOADING
More info in javadoc (http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatype-hibernate/javadoc/h4-2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/hibernate4/Hibernate4Module.Feature.html#FORCE_LAZY_LOADING) or code on github

Answer (score 0):

Add two more annotations into your code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POST")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "postId" )
public class Post implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "POST_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy-GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer postId;

    //Rest of the class
}
```

And:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TAG")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "tagId" )
public class Tag implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TAG_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy-GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer tagId;

    //Rest of the class
}
```

As the Jackson documentation says:

> In practice this is done by serializing the first instance as full object and object identity, and other references to the object as reference values.